# Quine with prime sourcecode character distribution constraints

Tags: code-golf, primes, quine, fibonacci

1. Your program should take no input, and no network or other connections.
2. Your program should output it's sourcecode.
3. The sourcecode must consist of **3 types** of characters: Numeric (0-9), Alpha (a-z|A-Z) and symbols !(0-9|a-z|A-Z). Constraints for the distribution of characters is:

   - 3.1. Every neighbouring characters with equal character-type makes a character-group.
   - 3.2. Each character-group **length in bytes** must be a **prime**-number (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, ...)
   - 3.3. The total number of **character-groups** of each character-type must be a **neighbouring (but not equal) fibonacci** sequence number. For example: 3 groups of numbers, 5 groups of alpha, 8 groups of symbols.
   - 3.4. A character-group of one charater-type cannot be adjacent to another character-group of the same character-type, because that will create one bigger group instead.

**Example** valid sourcecode (regarding character distribution, it does however not output it's sourcecode):

```
"."."."aa321'","/hithere' 12345678901,.,.,12345,.,
```

Character distribution in the example: 2 groups of Alpha. 3 group of numeric. 5 groups of other characters. The numbers 2, 3 and 5 are neighbouring numbers in the fibonacci sequence.

This is code-golf, good luck have fun!

Comment: You might want to disallow trivial solutions like any numeric literal in golfscript before it's too late.

Comment: I believe the somewhat boring quine `12` would be legal in J, GolfScript, etc under these rules (2 being a prime number and 1 being a fibonacci number).

Comment: The sourcecode must consist of all 3 types of characters, so it is atleast 6 character-groups

Comment: neighbours in the fibonacci sequence

Comment: so, 0 doesn't count as a fibonacci number?

Comment: It does, but the code must contain all three types of characters. So rule 3 invalidates 0 groups of one character-type.

Comment: Oh, I see, "Your source code must consist of **3 types** of characters". I read that as a partitioning of the characters rather than a requirement in itself, at first.

Comment: do `1` and `1` count as neighbouring fibonacci numbers? Or, are we even allowed to use "neighbouring or equal" character group counts? Also, does `1` count as a prime?

Comment: If there is 1 group of any character-type, that is the 1 neighbouring 2 in the fibonacci sequece, so 1 and 1 does not count as neighbouring numbers in the fibonacci sequence in this code-golf. Atleast 6 character-groups. 1 does not count as a prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PHP, some other languages - 12 bytes

```
22ab,,22,,22
```

PHP will print out the source code if it is not wrapped in some tag.

This is actually the smallest possible answer to the question. The smallest prime number is `2`, and the smallest distinct fibonacci numbers are `1`, `2`, and `3`. `3 + 2 + 1 = 6`. `6 * 2 = 12`

See a run here: http://ideone.com/0NDA8A

Answer (score 3):

## Golfscript, <del>21</del> 15 characters

```
11{'aa.~' }aa.~
```

After removing all NOPs, their images, and the leading `11`, this becomes the quine

```
{`'.~'}.~
```

reading: block(string(dup, eval)); dup; eval.

<del>Now to shoot for the stars (20 characters - the minimum for 2-3-5) or even galaxies (12 characters - the absolute minimum)</del>  I've taken a short stop at Alpha Centauri B to refuel, now I'm drifting through intergalactic medium. Thanks,  [Goldbach's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture).

Live: http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MTF7J2FhLn4nMTE7fWFhLn4K

Comment: @Plarsen shaved off six characters. One more to go, then I believe I'll hit the rock bottom for golfscript.

Comment: oh man! I could never imagine that was even possible!

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge 98 - 16 bytes

```
<@,*+982aa,,kd$"
```

This works only if your interpreter interprets line-wrap as adding a single space. This one works otherwise:

```
<@,*+982aa,,kd "
```

Character groups:

```
<@,*+ 5 chars, symbols
982   3 chars, numbers
aa    2 chars, alpha
,,    2 chars, symbols
kd    2 chars, alpha
$"    2 chars, symbols
```

So the fibonacci numbers are 1 (numbers), 2 (alpha), and 3 (symbols)

Answer (score 2):

### Windows Command Script - 12 bytes (+ free folder bonus)

```
md  12##56##
```

Since every command is echoed by default, it's just a matter of finding the shortest command.